# build.gradle.kts failed : Unresolved reference python,pip, jni,install

Tags: python, android, gradle-kotlin-dsl, aar, chaquopy

I'm new to android development and working on a Mobile solution, where Python Script has to be executed from android, from the documentation came to know chaquopy plugin should be used to execute Python Script in Android.

The expectation of requirement is to bundle all the dependencies/jars/plugins and python code in Android Library(AAR), and this AAR should be encapsulated in a way without doing any changes to main app should work (since I'm not the owner of the main app, no changes will be allowed)

However, for testing AAR I have a received cloned version of Main App.

Below is the AAR build.gradle.kts file code.

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("android")
    id("gradle-pega-android-module" )
    id("com.chaquo.python") version "13.0.0"
}

group = "com.***.***"
version = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

android {
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = 33


        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        python {
                pip {
                install("six")
                install("pandas")

            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters("armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64")
        }

        sourceSets.main {
            jni.srcDirs = listOf()
            jniLibs.srcDir("src/main/libs")
        }
        sourceSets {
            named("main") {
                // let gradle pack the shared library into apk
                jniLibs.srcDirs = listOf("../distribution/gperf/lib","../distribution/conda-android-python/lib")
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:runner:1.4.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0-alpha06")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")
    implementation("com.google.mlkit:image-labeling:17.0.7")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:18.0.2")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-image-labeling:16.0.8")
    implementation("com.chaquo.python:gradle:13.0.0")
}
```

While doing the build getting below errors.

```
Unresolved reference: python
Unresolved reference: pip
Unresolved reference: install
Unresolved reference: install
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline operator fun <T : Any, C : NamedDomainObjectContainer<TypeVariable(T)>> TypeVariable(C).invoke(configuration: Action<NamedDomainObjectContainerScope<TypeVariable(T)>>): TypeVariable(C) defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public operator fun <T> Closure<TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(): TypeVariable(T) defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public operator fun <T> Closure<TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(x: Any?): TypeVariable(T) defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public operator fun <T> Closure<TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(vararg xs: Any?): TypeVariable(T) defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public operator fun <V> Callable<TypeVariable(V)>.invoke(): TypeVariable(V) defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public operator fun <T, R> DeepRecursiveFunction<TypeVariable(T), TypeVariable(R)>.invoke(value: TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(R) defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> Action<in TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(target: TypeVariable(T)): Unit defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public operator fun <T> NamedDomainObjectProvider<TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(action: TypeVariable(T).() -> Unit): Unit defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public operator fun ArtifactHandler.invoke(configuration: ArtifactHandlerScope.() -> Unit): Unit defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public operator fun DependencyConstraintHandler.invoke(configuration: DependencyConstraintHandlerScope.() -> Unit): Unit defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public inline operator fun <T> ExtraPropertiesExtension.invoke(initialValueProvider: () -> TypeVariable(T)): InitialValueExtraPropertyDelegateProvider<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public operator fun <T> ExtraPropertiesExtension.invoke(initialValue: TypeVariable(T)): InitialValueExtraPropertyDelegateProvider<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public operator fun <T> Spec<TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(arg: TypeVariable(T)): Boolean defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public inline operator fun TaskContainer.invoke(configuration: TaskContainerScope.() -> Unit): TaskContainer defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
Expression 'main' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public val NamedDomainObjectContainer<KotlinSourceSet>.main: NamedDomainObjectProvider<KotlinSourceSet> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
Unresolved reference: jni
Variable expected
Not enough information to infer type variable T
Unresolved reference: jniLibs
Function invocation 'srcDirs(...)' expected
Variable expected
Calls to BasePlugin.getExtension() are deprecated and will be removed in AGP 8.0
Script compilation errors:
```

Any inputs or alternate approaches without doing any changes to main app will be great helpful.

Comment: It's possible that the Gradle plugin `com.chaquo.python` doesn't support the Gradle Kotlin DSL https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/231. You _might_ be able to use [Kotlin/Groovy interop](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:interoperability) to work around this issue.